# Label encoding with dplyr

Tags: r, encoding, dplyr, categories, categorical-data

Is there a label encoding functionality for dplyor in R, i.e. something which would transform

```
cat
dog
cat
```

to

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: you don't need `dplyr`.  Base R has `as.numeric(as.factor(x))`.

Comment: or `match(x, unique(x))`.

Comment: Thx Ben, pleas post this as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BenBolker points out, you can create a factor and extract its numeric values.

```
vec <- c("cat", "dog", "cat")

as.integer(factor(vec))
# [1] 1 2 1
```